# Does return-by-value mean extra copies and extra overhead? C++

Tags: c++, constructor, return-by-value

Consider the following:

```
class Foo { ... };

Foo rbv();

void caller()
{
  Foo x = rbv(); ← the return-value of rbv() goes into x
  ...
}

Foo rbv()
{
  ...
  return Foo(42, 73); ← suppose Foo has a ctor Foo::Foo(int a, int b)
}
```

How many objects of type Foo will be constructed?

Comment: Add a log message in a constructor for `Foo` and find out :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe.

In C++11, values are returned by moving, rather than copying, if they have a move constructor. This can be much more efficient than copying.

In some circumstances - such as when returning a local variable or a temporary (as you do here) - the move or copy can be *elided*. The value is created directly into the caller's stack frame, so that it doesn't need to be moved or copied on return. People who like acronyms sometimes call this (N)RVO - (Named) Return Value Optimisation.

Likewise, the copy or move from the temporary return value to `x` can also be elided.

Any decent compiler will implement this optimisation, so your code should only create a single `Foo`. You can verify this by making the destructor print a message, and observing that it only does this once: http://ideone.com/xydJqY. If you disable the optimisation, there may be up to three objects.

Answer (score 1):

There may be up to two copies: One from the temporary `Foo(42, 73)` to the return value of the function, and another from the return value of the function to `x`. However, both of those copies are eligible for copy elision, which allows for not making copies and instead constructing the object directly in the destination, equivalent to `Foo x(42, 73);`.

You may be able to control the extent to which your compiler takes advantage of copy elision; for example, in GCC you can use `-fno-elide-constructors` to get all two copies.